# Working with object Zend\View\Helper\Url, from the controller

Tags: php, zend-framework2

sorry for my bad english, i'm from Russia

began to learn zend framework 2...
Sample in controller, readAction():

```
use Zend\View\Helper\Url;

....

$helperUrl = new Url();
$address  = $helperUrl('news', array('action' => 'index'));
```

**As a result, thrown exception:**

```
Zend\View\Exception\RuntimeException

File:
    W:\home\zf2\vendor\zendframework\
       zendframework\library\Zend\View\Helper\Url.php:80
Message:
    No RouteStackInterface instance provided
```

Please, help me.
what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't use a viewhelper in a controller - and you don't need to.
There's also a `Url` controller plugin that does pretty much the same.

Controller plugins are invokable classes, you can use them like this (controller's action context):

```
$url = $this->url()->fromRoute($route, $params, $options, $reuseMatchesParams);
```

All parameters are optional. For further information, check the code in `Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\Url` or read the [docs](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html).

Comment: not true. you can use view helper in controller, but ofc is not very good idea:

$uVH = $this->getServiceLocator()->get( 'viewhelpermanager' )->get( 'url' ); 

$routeUrl = $uvh('route-name',array('param1'=>'param1')); 

etc

Answer (score 3):

Helpers and plugins, while they can be directly instantiated, usually shouldn't, as they typically are managed by a PluginManager. The PluginManager is a subclass of the ServiceManager, and, as such, provides a lot of functionality around plugin creation, including injection of standard collaborators, usage of factories to provide dependency injection, and more.

In the case of the Url helper, there is a factory that ensures it has the configured router injected -- if you instantiate it directly, you won't have this, and it won't be able to do its job, as you noticed!

As Daniel noted, you also want to make sure you're getting a plugin that's appropriate for the context. If you're in a controller, check to see if there's a controller plugin that will do the job for you. Daniel linked to the docs in his post.

Comment: u saved me from headache :-)

Answer (score 0):

I know there is already an accepted answer but I'll still post this to lessen the burden of beginners like me.

I use smarty as view renderer and in smarty you can't use php codes in the views, thus, everything must be done in the controller, allocating them in variables then passing them to the views.

You can use this:

```
$url = $this->url()->fromRoute('route',array('name'=>'route-name'));
```

If you are following the tutorial of zend 2, it will be like this:

```
$url = $this->url()->fromRoute('album',array('action'=>'add'));
$url = $this->url()->fromRoute('album',array('action'=>'edit'));
$url = $this->url()->fromRoute('album',array('action'=>'delete'));
```

This will have a value of:

```
/zf2/index.php/album/add
/zf2/index.php/album/edit
/zf2/index.php/album/delete
```

As you can see, you need to add the server name to it, which you can do by using these before the generating the route url:

```
$url = $uri = $this->getRequest()->getUri();
$url = sprintf('%s://%s', $uri->getScheme(), $uri->getHost());
```

Overall, the code snippet should look like this:

```
$url = $uri = $this->getRequest()->getUri();
$url = sprintf('%s://%s', $uri->getScheme(), $uri->getHost());
$url .= $this->url()->fromRoute('album',array('action'=>'add'));
```

To produce:

```
http://yourservername/zf2/index.php/album/add
```

Hope this helps beginner zf2 users